# What happens if MySQL gets same UPDATE query at the same time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like this:

```
UPDATE persons SET processing = :processing WHERE processing IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

What if the script gets called twice at the exact time to execute this query?
Is it possible that it just updates the **same** row twice?

Comment: SQL queries are beeing queued so the query is going to run twice.

Comment: But does it update the same row?

Comment: No because its being queued. You can see it as an `waiting list` for queries.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, `UPDATE` holds an exclusive lock on table/row and so by the time one `UPDATE` in process another will be queued. For more security and to enforce this behavior you must consider running your DML operations inside a `Transaction Block`.

Also, do you really need that `LIMIT 1` in your `UPDATE` statement?

In your case, No `UPDATE` will not happen twice cause see the `WHERE` condition. In first update the `processing` column is NULL and so will get updated to passed input but in second attempt the condition `WHERE processing IS NULL` will be `false` for this row and hence will skip the `UPDATE`.

Comment: Ok, so you can say it will not update the same row twice, right?

Comment: That will never happen because the cell you updating is the same cell you are checking to be `NULL`.

Comment: @S.Visser, absolutely correct; my bad was not thinking about the condition. Already updated that point.

Comment: Even if the query were to update the same row twice, which won't happen, the update will not propagate unless it changes the record. That means if your first fictional update changes something, the second one doesn't get "applied" if it holds the same values. MySQL takes care of many things when it comes to concurrency, so this isn't something developers should worry about in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

It will execute it twice, atomically. If `processing` is changed to not null, then the second operation in the queue will do nothing.

If you are thinking about the 'rows_affected' value, it will say 0 rows affected the second time, that is unless you change a connection parameter that tells it to return any rows *found* rather than actually modified.

---

Re-interpreting your question, if you have a table of multiple `processing` entries, with multiple being NULL, then **no** it will not update the same one, two of them will be set.